# How can I confirm my message was received using Android Beam?

Tags: java, android, nfc, android-beam

I'm having success creating an application which sends data through NFC/Android Beam. I am using `setNdefPushMessageCallback` and wondered how I can detect once the recipient phone has received the message? At the moment, I'm struggling to differentiate between failed and successful beams!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a callback with [NfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback%28android.nfc.NfcAdapter.OnNdefPushCompleteCallback,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.app.Activity...%29). It will be called when the transfer via Beam is successful.

Comment: Thanks! Looking into this now, is there any chance you could post an example which just logs or raises a toast when the message was successful?

Comment: I was able to implement it following this explanation: http://www.tappednfc.com/wp-content/uploads/TAPPED-NFCDeveloperGuide-Part1.pdf